# Making a Contact Form 7 calendar entry "required"

Tags: plugins, contact

I'm using the Contact Form 7 Calendar "plugin plugin", but I can't figure out how to make the date field required. The syntax is `[datetimepicker your-label]`, and in the parent plugin (Contact Form 7), you would just put an asterisk in, like `[datetimepicker* your-label]` but this doesn't work with the calendar widget... Of course, I could always style it in CSS to appear as if its required, but I kinda need the validation there. I've looked in the plugin's documentation, but this isn't covered, and the author is not responding on the WP Support Forums.

Has anyone used the Calendar add-on and been able to make the date field required? Anything I can do to tweak the javascript or whatever is used for validation -- I'm assuming its javascript (I'm sure js is very easy but I've never managed to find the time to learn it)? Or the php (I'm much more comfortable in php), but without breaking on plugin updates...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the answer is to read the installation instructions properly the first time round. The syntax within a contact 7 form is: `[cf7cal inputname]` or `[cf7cal* inputname]`